# Fatou's lemma and $\limsup \int_C |f_n|^p d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_1,f_2,... ,f \in \mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, where ${f_n}\to f$ a.e. and $\lim_n ||f_n||_p=||f||_p$.

We can find $A \in \mathscr{A}$ s.t. ${f_n}\to f$ uniformly with $\mu(A^c)< \epsilon$, and $\lim_n \int_A |f_n-f|^p d\mu=0$.

Let $C=X-A$. Is it possible to show $\limsup_n \int_C |f_n|^p d\mu \leq \int_C |f|^p d\mu$ with the help of Fatou's lemma?

Comment: $\int_C |f_n|^{p}d\mu= \int_X |f_n|^{p}d\mu-\int_A |f_n|^{p}d\mu$

Comment: @geetha290krm this can only shows
$lim \int_C |f_n|^p d\mu =lim \int_X |f_n|^p d\mu - lim \int_A |f_n|^p d\mu=\int_X |f|^p d\mu -lim \int_A |f_n|^p d\mu$

I cannot see how this helps.

Comment: Continuing from what I wrote:
$\leq \int_X |f|^p d\mu - liminf \int_A |f_n|^p d\mu$
By Fatou's Lemma we have $\leq \int_X |f|^p d\mu - \int_A lim|f_n|^p d\mu$
$=\int_X |f|^p d\mu - \int_A |f|^p d\mu =\int_C |f|^p d\mu$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect!